# gdbus.error:org.freedesktop.policykit1.error.failed:unix process subject does not have uid set - Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: mount

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04, and after the upgrade I could not access one of my Windows NTFS drives. The error message is:

> gdbus.error:org.freedesktop.policykit1.error.failed:unix process subject does not have uid set.

Other NTFS drives open, but this one gives an error.

Comment: Can you list the steps you usually take to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact same problem here - couldn't access the drive via "Files" (Nautilus), with same error message.
It appeared to be mounted, though. So I copied the files I needed via the terminal.
After that the Disk showed up normally, also after unmounting/mounting it.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/04/workaround-nautilus-admin-not-working-ubuntu-21-04/,
*This usually happens when you use “Open as Administrator” or “Edit as Administrator” to open folder or edit file via root. Or when you trying to access another user folder in system, and even using nautilus admin://, gedit admin://, or other commands in your script or console.*

So it offers two options; download & install the gvfs .deb packages for the previous Ubuntu 20.10 or use its own repository with release GVfs 1.48.1 package which corrects the error.